# Repeated (Array) two-way lookup in matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a two-way matrix lookup in with an array of cells.

I have a matrix with plant names in both rows and column headers. In the matrix it has a "v" in cells that have a combination of plants that combine well, and an x for plants that don't combine well.

Now I have a table with plants that are combined in one bed:

- plant 1
- plant 2
- plant 3
- plant 4
- etc

For each plant I want to lookup in the matrix if any of the other plants in that bed combine well, or not well with this plant.

```
{=INDEX(Matrix!$A$1:$J$10; MATCH(A2;Matrix!$B:$B;0); MATCH($A$3:$A$6;Matrix!$A$2:$J$2;0))="v"}
```

- Matrix!!$A$1:$J$10 is the range where all the values in the matrix are (x's and v's)
- A2 is the current plant that is being looked up in the matrix
- Matrix!$B:$B is the column with all the plant names in the rows
- Matrix!A2:J2 is the row with all the plant names in the columns
- $A$3:$A$6 is the range with all the plants in the current bed (including the currrent plant being looked up)`

I would expect this two-way matrix function to work, but it doesn't work as expected. Some of the combinations of plants it finds, and others not. I have also tried to split this two-way lookup into two parts:
- all plants in the bed before the current plant
- all plants in the bed after the current plant

This way the current plant is not being lookup against itself, but I would not expect that to be a problem anyway.

I have [attached](http://www.mvanderveen.nl/Plants.xlsx) an simplified example that illustrates my problem. On the beds sheet you can find the formulas. Those marked green have the correct result. Those marked red have the wrong result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've answered something similar earlier today:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882542/conditional-vlook-up-without-using-vba/28882768#28882768

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is the right approach. How can "combines well" and "does not combine well" be both true (desired event in row 4). Oh, and you are missing the curly brackets in the 'Andijvie' row.

Comment: Tom, thank you for your quick answer. The does not combine well will prevail over the other. However, I am not sure the question you answered before is the same as my question. the IF and SMALL are used for a lookup with a fixed column. However, I have a two-way lookup where the row number has to be found by comparing to the current cell value, and the column rows have to be found by using multiple values in a range (through a array formula). If you still think this can be done with the functions you described before, I would be eager to see an example.